Chemistry figure with TikZ
I'm trying to replicate the following figure:
.
I did (in a crude way) succeed to make the boxes, but I don't know how to make the large brackets and the various text in it. This is what I have now:
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\LARGE]
\draw  (3,11.25) rectangle (3.75,10.5);
\draw  (3,10.5) rectangle (6,8.25);
\draw (3.75,10.5) -- (3.75,8.25);
\draw (6,9.75) -- (3,9.75);
\draw (6,9) -- (3,9);
\draw (4.5,10.5) -- (4.5,8.25);
\draw (5.25,10.5) -- (5.25,8.25);
\draw  (6,9.75) rectangle (9.75,8.25);
\draw (6,9) -- (9.75,9);
\draw (6.75,8.25) -- (6.75,9.75);
\draw (7.5,8.25) -- (7.5,9.75);
\draw (8.25,8.25) -- (8.25,9.75);
\draw (9,8.25) -- (9,9.75);
\draw  (9.75,9) rectangle (14.25,8.25);
\draw  (14.25,9) rectangle (15,8.25);
\draw (10.5,9) -- (10.5,8.25);
\draw (11.25,9) -- (11.25,8.25);
\draw (12,9) -- (12,8.25);
\draw (12.75,9) -- (12.75,8.25);
\draw (13.5,9) -- (13.5,8.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

which produces the following:
.
Can somebody please help me?

My tikz code is as follows.

\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,mybrace/.style={magenta,decorate,line width=1pt,decoration={brace,raise=2pt,amplitude=5pt}}]
\draw 
(0,0) grid +(1,4)
(1,0) grid +(3,3)
(4,0) grid +(5,2)
(9,0) grid +(7,1)
;
\path 
(0,.5)  node[left=2mm]{$n=4$} (16,.5)  node[right=2mm]{$4s,4p,4d,4f$}
(0,1.5) node[left=2mm]{$n=3$} (16,1.5) node[right=2mm]{$3s,3p,3d$}
(0,2.5) node[left=2mm]{$n=2$} (16,2.5) node[right=2mm]{$2s,2p$}
(0,3.5) node[left=2mm]{$n=1$} (16,3.5) node[right=2mm]{$1s$}
;
\path (0,4)--+(1,0) node[midway,above]{$l=0$};
\draw[mybrace] (1,3)--+(3,0) node[black,midway,above=1.5mm]{$l=1$};
\draw[mybrace] (4,2)--+(5,0) node[black,midway,above=1.5mm]{$l=2$};
\draw[mybrace] (9,1)--+(7,0) node[black,midway,above=1.5mm]{$l=3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Like this?

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 0pt,
%every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
   start chain = going right,      
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{% Brace Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=2pt,
        post=moveto, post length=2pt,
        raise=#1},% for mirroring of brace
        thick,
        pen colour={#2}  },
BC/.default = 1mm/red,
      N/.style = {draw, minimum size=8mm, outer sep=0pt,
                 node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (n11) [N, label=left:{$n=1$}, label={$l=0$}];
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node   [N, label=left:{$n=2$}, below=of n11];
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
\node (n2\i) [N];
    \end{scope}
\draw[BC]   (n22.north west) -- node[above=3mm] {$l=1$} (n24.north east);
%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node   [N, label=left:{$n=3$}, below=of n21];
    \foreach \i in {1,...,9}
\node (n3\i) [N];
    \end{scope}
\draw[BC]   (n35.north west) -- node[above=3mm] {$l=2$} (n39.north east);
%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain}]
\node   [N, label=left:{$n=4$}, below=of n31];
    \foreach \i in {1,...,16}
\node (n4\i) [N];
    \end{scope}
\draw[BC]   (n410.north west) -- node[above=3mm] {$l=3$} (n416.north east);
%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={anchor=west}]
\node   at (n11 -| n416.east) {$1s$};
\node   at (n21 -| n416.east) {$2s, 2p$};
\node   at (n31 -| n416.east) {$3s, 3p, 3d$};
\node[label={[anchor=north east]south east:etc.}]   at (n416.east) {$4s, 4p, 4d, 4f$};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

You can change color of braces and their shortness (defined by pre  length=2pt, and post  length=2pt,) according to your taste.
I wonder how this image is connected to chemistry as you stated in question title.

First of, thank you so much for your solution. Second, that image is from a famous Italian chemistry book and basically helps in building orbital filling diagrams.


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\rect#1#2{\node[draw, minimum width = 1cm, inner sep = 0pt, minimum height = 1cm] (#2) at (#1) {};}
        
        \rect{0,0}{A-0}
        \foreach \x in {0,...,3}{\rect{\x,-1}{B-\x}}
        \foreach \x in {0,...,8}{\rect{\x,-2}{C-\x}}
        \foreach \x in {0,...,15}{\rect{\x,-3}{D-\x}}
        \foreach \p/\n in {A/1,B/2,C/3,D/4}{\node[anchor = east] at (\p-0.west){$n=\n$};}
        \node[anchor=west] at (D-15.east) {$4s,4p,4d,4f$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (D-15.east |- C-0) {$3s,3p,3d$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (D-15.east |- B-0) {$2s,2p$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (D-15.east |- A-0) {$1s$};
        \tikzset{brace/.style = {line width = 0.75pt, decorate, decoration = {brace, raise = 3pt, amplitude = 3pt}}}
        \tikzset{label/.style = {midway, yshift = 1.25em}}
        \node[anchor = south] at (A-0.north) {$l=0$};
        \draw[brace] (B-0.north east)--(B-3.north east) node[label]{$l=1$};
        \draw[brace] (C-4.north east)--(C-8.north east) node[label]{$l=2$};
        \draw[brace] (D-9.north east)--(D-15.north east) node[label]{$l=3$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

and: 
